# Diffeomorphism and hyperbolic points

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems

Suppose $f$ is a diffeomorphism.Prove that all hyperbolic periodic points are isolated.

I tried using the mean value theorem using two diferent periodic points (assuming the periodic points arent isolated)
Reaching that exist $x_0$ between the periodic points with $f'(x_0)=1$
But thats the way?
I only want a hint or something
Thanks

Comment: Back up. What manifold are you working with? You seem to be thinking $\Bbb R$ only. Let's also write down all the relevant definitions.

Comment: Yes im working in $\Bbb R$

Comment: How does a diffeo of $\Bbb R$ have a periodic point other than a fixed point?

Comment: A diffeo of $\Bbb R$ can only have fixed points and periodic points of prime period 2

Comment: Ok, true. So if you have a non-isolated fixed point $a$ of either $f$ or $f^2$, compute $f'(a)$ (or $(f^2)'(a)$) using that sequence of fixed points.

Comment: Using the sequence we obtain $f'(a)=1$ and this is a contradiction.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

I think the following could be the sketch of a proof:

Take $x_*$ as a non-isolated hyperbolic point, then in any small neighbourhood there is another non-isolated h.p. $y_*$ s.t. $|x_* - y_*| < \epsilon$. Then $f'(x_*) \sim \frac{|f(x_*) - f(y_*)|}{|x_* - y_*|} = 1$. This would contradict the definition of hyperbolicity.